# Why do I have to replace all hyphens with underscores when calling modules with py launcher?

Tags: python, windows, pylauncher

I'm using the [Python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) on Windows to simplify version management and avoid modifying system path.

I've successfully installed a few packages:

```
> py -m pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
Brotli             1.0.9
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.12
gallery-dl         1.21.1
idna               3.3
mutagen            1.45.1
pip                22.0.4
pycryptodomex      3.14.1
requests           2.27.1
setuptools         58.1.0
urllib3            1.26.9
websockets         10.3
yt-dlp             2022.4.8
```

They're all listed under `Program Files/Python310/Scripts`:

[image]

but when I try to call them I get the following error:

```
> py -m gallery-dl
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe: No module named gallery-dl
```

unless I replace hyphens with underscores:

```
> py -m gallery_dl --help
usage: __main__.py [OPTION]... URL...

General Options:
...
```

This is quite different from when I wasn't using the launcher and had python in PATH and could just call `gallery-dl` inside Powershell without:

- prepending `py -m` - which is fine
- replacing hyphens with underscores - which is less fine because it sort of feels like I'm calling a raw function
- having the `__main__.py:` bit - which doesn't feel right either.

Is this the expected and proper behavior, or [am I doing / did I do] something wrong?

Comment: Check folder `Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages` rather than `Program Files/Python310/Scripts`.

Comment: That folder contains two folders per package (with appended version and without).